# How to match a string in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have three arrays that contain different sets of hostnames:

```
webserver = [
  "ws1.xyz.com",
  "ws2.xyz.com",
  "ws3.xyz.com"
  ]
dbserver = [
  "db1.xyz.com",
  "db2.xyz.com",
  "db3.xyz.com"
]
appserver = [
  "app1.xyz.com",
  "app2.xyz.com",
  "app3.xyz.com"
]
```

I want to identify the current host in one of those arrays that is running the script. Here's what I've got, so far:

```
require "socket"

host_name = Socket::gethostname
if webserver.grep(/#{host_name}/)
  puts "You're a web server"
elsif dbserver.grep(/#{host_name}/)
  puts "You're a db server"
elsif appserver.grep(/#{host_name}/)
  puts "You're an app server"
else
  puts "You're not in any group"
end
```

It always matches the first `if` block.

Comment: @ndn:  Looks like it's returning the host name of the machine.  If one were in a terminal which read `ndm@snazzybox`, then `Socket::gethostname` would return `snazzybox`.

Comment: I'm *fairly* confident that it would yield similar results.  That is to say, they're not going to be getting *any* FQDN information with their current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you get that result, but a better way is:

```
case Socket.gethostname
when *webserver then puts "You're a web server"
when *dbserver  then puts "You're a db server"
when *appserver then puts "You're an app server"
else                 puts "You're not in any group"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) always returns an array. Even if the value is not found, it will just return an empty array. In Ruby, all values, except for `false` and `nil`, are considered falsy. Therefore, no matter what and where you grep,

```
if array.grep(/something/)
  # do something
end
```

`do something` will always be executed. As to what to do instead - you can make [`Array#empty?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F) checks on the results, but [@sawa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32662300/2423164) is the most idiomatic way to go.

Answer (score -1):

The really easy way to do this is...

```
if webserver.include?(host_name)
...
```

Comment: @ndn true it may need to be modified based on OP's response.